# fft of a complex signal

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft

I am new to dsp and just have a vague understanding of fft process. i know fft is used to convert time to freq domain.... i need to generate a sequence of frequencies such that F=[F1,F2,.....Fn-1] where n=16 and then need to do the ifft of it.... i need these freq sequences to be random... My friend told me that the sequence should have both Cos and sin wave making up (a+ib) an complex waveform.... Because i chose random signal in matlab using command rand and he told it generates random signals but only in positive x axis... he said something about choosing any random points from a circle.. i didn't quite understand what he meant by circle... can someone pls explain in simple words... I browsed all over and found fft only for sin or cos wave... how can i input a complex waveform to the fft so that i get a complex freq sequence becoz i read a fft returns a complex value... so am i supposed to input either sin or cos wave and get a complex output or should i input a complex wave... can someone give me a brief code in matlab since i'm trying to implement on matlab so that i can build on the code.. Also i know we input a time domain signal and th signal is sampled and we get bins which builds the freq.. i'm not quite clear in wat way we r supposed to sample and how it is build.. can someone also give an explanation not involving too much maths... Thank you

Comment: First generate the signal s(t) via an iFFT process from a sequence of frequency values: f = [f0, · · · , fn−1.] Choosing n = 16, set up a matlab script that computes the iFFT, add a pulse waveform to its output, and computes the spectrum of s(t) .Chose F such that |fn| = 1, which gives a flat frequency response. This signal s(t) is a pseudo random sequence... and i need to convolute this s(t) with my pulse waveform (binary seq) to see if i'm getting a shaped spectrum.... this is wat i am trying to achieve

Comment: this is my matlab code------------------------------------%generating uniformly distibuted random frequencies between 1Mhz and 2Mhz

x=1e6+(2e6-1e6).*rand(1,16);


%calculating ifft of frequencies
y=ifft(x);



%generating a pulse wave form with 2Ghz freq with a sample rate of 20Ghz

fc=2e6;
fs = 4e6; % sample freq
t = 1 : 1/fs : (1/(2*fc))-(1/fs) ;
p(t*fs) = 0;
l =  1/(2*fc): 1/fs : 1/(fc);
p(l*fs) = 1;

%adding pulse to the IFFT 
for i=1:1:16
data(length(p)*(i-1)+1:length(p)*i)=conv(abs(y(i)),p);
end

Answer (score 1):

The FFT converts a time-domain signal, which is a series of real numbers, into the frequency domain, as a series of complex numbers.  The IFFT converts back again - from the frequency to the time domain.

If I understand correctly, you are trying to produce a series of random amplitudes in the frequency domain, so that you get a random signal back in the time domain when you apply the IFFT.  However, convential random numbers are all real-valued, not complex.

The result of an FFT is a sequence of complex numbers of the form (x + iy).  This is equivalent to the Cartesian coordinates (x, y).  However, it is often easier to think of the FFT results in terms of polar coordinates (r, θ).  Here, r represents the amplitude and θ the phase.

So one way to do what you want is to generate a random amplitude r, and a random phase 0 ≤ θ < 2π.  Then convert that from polar to Cartesian form.  Convert the Cartesian pair to a complex number.

As for the circles - once you've picked your amplitude r, then picking the phase θ is effectively picking one point at random around a circle of radius r.

Aside: The only difference between a sine wave and a cosine wave is the phase.  If you feed a pure sine wave into an FFT, you will get a particular complex number out.  If you feed in a cosine wave of the same frequency and amplitude, the FFT result will have the same amplitude but a different phase.